# BASH sed expression optimisation or conversion to native bash substitution

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, substitution

I have a sed expression which might run anywhere from 0
to thousands of times, the input is piped and substituted:

```bash
somefunc() { sed "s/\s*//g; s/[\"\'~\!#\\\/\$%\^&\*\(\)\=]//g; s/\.\.//g"; }
```

And I simply use it like this:

```bash
echo 'Hello world' | somefunc
```

This is quite slow, so I tried to convert to a native bash substitution
and failed and I don't know if theres a way for me to optimise it,
so I decided to ask here

Is there a way to do this, maybe convert to a native bash substitution,
maybe use a different tool, anything that is even slightly faster helps

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe in words what you're doing in sed. Particularly the 2nd s/// regex

Comment: @glennjackman 1st: removes whitespace ***2nd: Removes disallowed characters ("'~!#\$%^&*()=
)*** 3rd: removes `..`

Comment: Can the list of disallowed characters be generalize as "punctuation" or is that list of characters specific?

Comment: @glennjackman `"'~!#\$%^&*/()=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
somefunc() {
    local tmp=${1//[[:space:]\"\'~!#\\$%^&*\/()=]/}
    printf '%s' "${tmp//../}"
}
```

Comment: Damnnn this sped it up by  A LOT  thank you !

Comment: It helps when you don't have to spawn an external command thousands of times.